# Ideas to make a great wall paper

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing

I have few photos in portrait mode. I wish to make a good wallpaper by removing the background and applying various photoshop techniques.

Can you please suggest me few tutorials or ideas to make a good wallpaper?

Answer (score 4):

A good wallpaper usually has an excellent use of "negative space". What I meant is that it is usually mostly empty and only a small area has any real content in it. The rest are left with lines/colors/empty.

Now, the placement of the main object is also important. The easiest is always to put it in the middle, but depending on the object itself, other placements may yield a more attractive result.

Here are some examples from [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/31/desktop-wallpaper-calendar-august-2010/).

Answer (score -1):

Check out http://www.mandolux.com/ for some amazing ideas.

Comment: This appears to have a single image in 4 sections, I guess for use on multiple monitors?